# How does HTTP header indicate a relative path

Tags: http, http-headers

My (working) code looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../AAAA/1111.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="BBBB/2222.js"></script>
```

The headers I see on the server side are:

```
GET /AAAA/1111.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8000/admin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: Idea-864a62cc=6c435764-3873-4567-a197-140cd7e7fac1

GET /BBBB/2222.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8000/admin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: Idea-864a62cc=6c435764-3873-4567-a197-140cd7e7fac1
```

How can I tell the path (on the server side) since they both look the same? One is below the referer and the other is in a sibling directory to the referer, yet I can't tell from the HTTP header.  The ".." info seems to be lost yet the server gets it right?  How does it know?

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Answer (score 0):

That's because the browser resolves relative references. See Section 5 of RFC 3986 for details.

So no, you can't tell these apart on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but if the server doesn't know, how does it know what resource to return?

Comment: It returns the resource that was asked for in the HTTP request. That's all the information it has.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, but if you look closer at my question you'll see I'm asking how does the server differentiate the two requests I show in my example with regard to the resource paths.  I show what the server sees and what the browser sees in terms of the HTML file.  There is obviously something more that I am missing because the information the server sees is inadequate (it's not a matter of an algorithm).

Comment: The server does not differentiate. All the information it has is what's in the request. I guess you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Turned out the problem was the server wasn't returning a Location header.  When I added that, all was good.  Thanks.